# Streaming video from AWS Kinesis to JS client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to consume the video from an AWS Kinesis stream. The stream is visible in the AWS console, but I cannot consume it in the JS application I'm trying to create.

I've been following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/how-hls.html#how-hls-ex1) tutorial, but cannot get the streaming URL.

My code is here:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { STREAM_NAME, ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, REGION } from '../secrets'

var streamName = STREAM_NAME;

// Step 1: Configure SDK Clients
var options = {
    accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: REGION
}
var kinesisVideo = new AWS.KinesisVideo(options);
var kinesisVideoArchivedContent = new AWS.KinesisVideoArchivedMedia(options);

// Step 2: Get a data endpoint for the stream
kinesisVideo.getDataEndpoint({
    StreamName: streamName,
    APIName: "GET_HLS_STREAMING_SESSION_URL"
}, function(err, response) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log('Data endpoint: ' + response.DataEndpoint);
    kinesisVideoArchivedContent.endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(response.DataEndpoint);
});

// Step 3: Get an HLS Streaming Session URL
console.log('Fetching HLS Streaming Session URL');
var playbackMode = 'LIVE'; // 'LIVE' or 'ON_DEMAND'
//var startTimestamp = new Date('START_TIMESTAMP'); // For ON_DEMAND only
//var endTimestamp = new Date('END_TIMESTAMP'); // For ON_DEMAND only
var fragmentSelectorType = 'SERVER_TIMESTAMP'; // 'SERVER_TIMESTAMP' or 'PRODUCER_TIMESTAMP'
const SESSION_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 60*60
console.log(kinesisVideo)
const hlsUrl = kinesisVideoArchivedContent.getHLSStreamingSessionURL({
    StreamName: streamName,
    //StreamARN: "arn:aws:kinesisvideo:us-east-1:635420739373:stream/mr-pinchers-dot-org/1561848963391",
    PlaybackMode: playbackMode,
    HLSFragmentSelector: {
        FragmentSelectorType: fragmentSelectorType,
        TimestampRange: playbackMode === 'LIVE' ? undefined : {
//            StartTimestamp: startTimestamp,
//            EndTimestamp: endTimestamp
        }
    },
    Expires: parseInt(SESSION_EXPIRATION_SECONDS)
}, function(err, response) {
    if (err) { return console.error("Darn", err); }
    console.log('HLS Streaming Session URL: ' + response.HLSStreamingSessionURL, response);
  }
)

console.log("here", hlsUrl)

class Home extends Component {
  render () {
    return <ReactPlayer url={hlsUrl} playing={true} />
  }
}

export default Home
```

The response I'm getting in Step 3 (response.HLSStreamingSessionURL) is undefined.

Step 2 runs fine, and I get an endpoint back, so I'm confident that it's not a permissions problem.

Part of me thinks that I should be using some async/await calls but I'm not sure, still pretty new to JS and all that async stuff so didn't know how to incorporate it into this.

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out but the documentation on Kinesis is still pretty light, although if someone has a good resource for it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic JavaScript async behavior. You're executing step 3 before step 2 is complete. You can't use the response before it's happened.

You can fix this by starting step 3 when step 2 has completed, as follows:

```
kinesisVideo.getDataEndpoint({
    StreamName: streamName,
    APIName: "GET_HLS_STREAMING_SESSION_URL"
}, function(err, response) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log('Data endpoint: ' + response.DataEndpoint);
    kinesisVideoArchivedContent.endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(response.DataEndpoint);

    var playbackMode = 'LIVE';
    var fragmentSelectorType = 'SERVER_TIMESTAMP';
    const SESSION_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 60*60

    kinesisVideoArchivedContent.getHLSStreamingSessionURL({...});
    // remainder of code here
});
```

Or you can use [async/await](https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-promises-and-why-async-await-wins-the-battle-4fc9d15d509f) and promise variants of the AWS SDK methods like so:

```
(async () => {
    const kv_response = await kv.getDataEndpoint({...}).promise();
    // ...
    const hls_response = await kvac.getHLSStreamingSessionURL({...}).promise();
})();
```

Note that `await` may only be used inside an `async` function, hence the anonymous async wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, and I appreciate the variants you gave.